# hadoop 2.0 shuffle benchmark

Tags: hadoop

I have found some page saying that hadoop 2.0 has a built-in benchmark testtool for shuffle.

But I'm unable to find it!

Could somebody guide me where to look for the same? I know in hadoop 0.20.* there is a test jar. But I can't find it in hadoop 2.0.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'testtool for shuffle', but if you look in $HADOOP_HOME there should be a file hadoop-test-*.jar and if you hadoop jar this you see what programs are available (some 20 should be listed, from DFSCIOTest over mapredtest to threadedmapbench)

Comment: I know where is the hadoop-test*.jar in hadoop version 0.20.*. But my problem is I can't find it in hadoop version 2.0

Comment: My final target is to do a benchmark for shuffle. And I had finished the benchmark test with DFSCIOTest .